# How to stop automatic network provisioning

Tags: networking, rhel

I recently installed RHEL 9 and attempted to delete all network interfaces. I removed all files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` folder and deleted the interface `ens192` with `nmutl`. However, after a reboot a new connection is built named `System ens192` tied to device `ens192` and set to DHCP.

How can I prevent this from automatically creating on boot?

Comment: Get rid of networkmangler ... it's trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. It was cloud-init overwriting the network configuration data.

Answer (score -1):

To prevent RHEL 9 from automatically recreating the ens192 network interface and setting it to DHCP on boot, you can disable the NetworkManager service and manually configure your network interfaces. Here are the steps to do this:

1. **Disable NetworkManager**:

   Stop and disable the NetworkManager service to prevent it from managing your network interfaces:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
   sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager
   ```
2. **Remove Network Configuration for ens192**:

   Check if there are any remaining configuration files for ens192:

   ```bash
   ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192
   ```

   If you see a file named `ifcfg-ens192`, remove it:

   ```bash
   sudo rm /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192
   ```
3. **Configure Network Interfaces Manually**:

   To configure your network interfaces manually, you'll need to create new configuration files for your network interfaces in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` directory. You can create a new configuration file, for example, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192-custom`, and define the settings you want for your network interface. Here's an example of what the file might look like for a static IP configuration:

   ```
   TYPE="Ethernet"
   BOOTPROTO="none"
   DEFROUTE="yes"
   IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
   IPV6INIT="yes"
   IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
   IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
   IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
   NAME="ens192"
   UUID="your-uuid-here"
   DEVICE="ens192"
   ONBOOT="yes"
   IPADDR="your-static-ip-here"
   PREFIX="your-subnet-prefix-here"
   GATEWAY="your-gateway-ip-here"
   DNS1="your-dns-server-ip-here"
   ```

   Replace the placeholders (`your-uuid-here`, `your-static-ip-here`, `your-subnet-prefix-here`, `your-gateway-ip-here`, `your-dns-server-ip-here`) with your actual network configuration details.
4. **Enable and Start Network Service**:

   Enable and start the network service:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-dispatcher
   sudo systemctl start NetworkManager-dispatcher
   ```
5. **Reboot**:

   Reboot your system to apply the changes:

   ```bash
   sudo reboot
   ```

After these steps, NetworkManager should no longer automatically recreate the ens192 network interface and set it to DHCP on boot. Instead, your network interfaces will be manually configured according to the settings you specified in your custom configuration file.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed steps. My system is now rebuilding ifcfg-ens192 on every reboot. I tried deleting it and building a ifcfg-ens192 with my configuraation but was overwritten on reboot. I then built ifcfg-ens192-1 with the desired config however on reboot the system is re-adding ifcfg-ens192 and both are set to on boot. The system created ifcfg-ens192 has a line AUTOCONNECT_PRIORITY=999.